# Move UIView to another UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have an `UIViewController` which contains 2 `UIScrollViews`, `scrollView1`, `scrollView2` for instance.

`scrollView1` contains many `UIViews`, when tapping one of it's `UIViews` I want it to move into `scrollView2`

When tapping a `UIView` that belongs to `scrollView1`, a method inside the `UIViewController` is being called and the `view` is passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In that method you  should write something like:

```
[view removeFromSuperview];
[scrollView2 addSubview:view];
```

**Edit**:

For animated move you should try something like:

```
CGPoint originalCenter = [self.view convertPoint:view.center fromView:scrollView1];
[view removeFromSuperView];
[self.view addSubview:view];
view.center = originalCenter;

CGPoint destinationPointInSecondScrollView = ; // Set it's value
CGPoint finalCenter = [self.view convertPoint:destinationPointInSecondScrollView fromView:scrollView2];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     view.center = finalCenter;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [view removeFromSuperView];
                         [scrollView2 addSubview:view];
                         view.center = destinationPointInSecondScrollView;
                     }];
```

Comment: Thanks, but id I want the view to actually move into scrollView2 using animation, how can I combine this in the animation?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have these two scrollViews declared as properties:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)]
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollView1.subviews) {
        [view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    }
}

- (void)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIView *view = gesture.view;
    [self moveToScrollView2:view];
}

- (void)moveToScrollView2:(UIView *)view
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.scrollView2 addSubview:view];
}
```